# How to get cell button name in button action in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, cell

I need tableview cell button name in button action

**code:** please guide me

```
class NewSearchResultCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var iButton: UIButton!

var actionBlock: (() -> Void)? = nil
}

class NewSearchViewController: UIViewController {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewSearchResultCell", for: indexPath) as! NewSearchResultCell

 cell.actionBlock = {
        cell.iButton.displayTooltip("Job should be completed within these dates!")
        }
 return cell

}

@IBAction func cellBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    actionBlock?()
}

}
```

Error:

> Cannot find 'actionBlock' in scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cellBtn` action must be inside the  `UITableViewCell` subclass and you can pass anything in the closure to the caller.

Just pass the reference to the cell because it could change if cells are inserted or deleted

```
class NewSearchResultCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var iButton: UIButton!

    var actionBlock: ((NewSearchResultCell) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func cellBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        actionBlock?(self)
    }
}
```

In the controller handle the passed cell

```
cell.actionBlock = { actualCell in
    actualCell.iButton.displayTooltip("Job should be completed within these dates!")
}
```